# I am trying to implement a camera feature onto my application but "app wont run"

Tags: java, android

So I have a functional application that has many pages and this is the registration 2 page that is supposed to open a standard android camera and then store it using the code at the bottom of the registration java page.

Here is my code:

```
    package com.example.mockups;

import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;

import java.io.File;


public class Register2 extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button button;
    ImageView imageView;
    static final int CAM_REQUEST = 1;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register2);
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonContinue);
        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent camera_intent = new Intent (MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                File file = getFile();
                camera_intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri. fromFile(file));
                startActivityForResult(camera_intent, CAM_REQUEST);

            }
        });
    }

    private File getFile()
    {
        File folder = new File("sdcard/camera");

        if (!folder.exists())
        {
            folder.mkdir();
        }

        File image_file = new File(folder, "cam_image.jpg");
        return image_file;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        String path = "sdcard/camera/cam_image.jpg";
        imageView.setImageDrawable(Drawable.createFromPath(path));

    }
}
_________________________________

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_register2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.strongholdmockups.Register2">

    <TextView
        android:text="Build Profile"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/buildProTitle"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display1"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <TextView
        android:text="Upload Profile Picture:"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="33dp"
        android:id="@+id/textView46"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/buildProTitle"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="36dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="36dp" />

    <Button
        android:text="Upload from Camera Roll"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="21dp"
        android:id="@+id/buttonContinue"
        style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.Button"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView46"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/buildProTitle"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/buildProTitle" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_view"
        android:layout_width="350dp"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/continueBtn1"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />


    <Button
        android:text="Continue"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="23dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="23dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
        android:id="@+id/continueBtn1"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless.Colored"
        android:background="@color/cardview_light_background"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Headline"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/image_view"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/image_view" />

</RelativeLayout>


__________________

      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Comment: Please say why your app won't run. What error do you get?

Comment: What does your log show?

Answer (score 0):

You have to check if permissions are granted for API version >= 23. Add something like this to your code before using the camera/external storage.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
    if (checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        Log.v(TAG,"Permission is granted");
        return true;
    } else {
        Log.v(TAG,"Permission is revoked");
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
        return false;
    }
}else { //permission is automatically granted on sdk<23 upon installation
    Log.v(TAG,"Permission is granted");
    return true;
}
```

Comment: No, add this code in the activity where you want to use the camera/external storage. This needs to be implemented before you start the camera activity.